# get values by max date and time

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, group-by, max

I have a table like this

| datetime | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-22 10:00:01 | Apple | 100 |
| 2021-09-22 12:02:01 | Apple | 101 |
| 2021-09-22 12:00:02 | Lemon | 150 |
| 2021-09-23 18:10:01 | Orange | 10 |
| 2021-09-23 19:31:02 | Orange | 9 |
| 2021-09-24 09:00:00 | Apple | 99 |
| 2021-09-26 00:00:00 | Banan | 15 |

I would like to get the values for each name by max datetime field for this name.

| name | value | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 99 | 2021-09-24 09:00:00 |
| Banan | 15 | 2021-09-26 00:00:00 |
| Orange | 9 | 2021-09-23 19:31:02 |
| Lemon | 150 | 2021-09-22 12:00:02 |

Comment: Do you want the latest date at the top or the time? Because according to your expected result, 24-09 is at the top when 26-09 is the later date.

Comment: Does your name column need to be ordered alphabetically as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (name) t.*
from t
order by name, datetime desc;
```

`distinct on` is a convenient Postgres extension that returns the first row for a group -- defined by the keys in parentheses.  "First" is based on the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This could help.

```
select distinct(name), value, datetime from table_name order by name asc, datetime desc;
```